# GNU dynamic replacement string

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using GNU parallel in Ubuntu 20.04.2. I tried to use the --plus option for parameter manipulation. But I couldn't get it to work, even as simple as the following command:

```
$ parallel --plus echo {/.gz/.st} ::: test.gz

$ {/.gz/.st} test.gz
```

I wonder what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was introduced in 20170322.

Your version is probably older.